# Selecting Data from Excel Spreadsheet Doesn't get First Row

Tags: vb.net

I'm using an OleDbDataReader to loop through my imported excel file and it gets everything in the file except for the first row. How can I specify that I want to see this header row?

```
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & firstSheetName & "]"

        Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection)
        Dim myDba As OleDbDataReader

        myDba = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        s = ""
        While myDba.Read()
            For i = 0 To myDba.FieldCount - 1
                s &= myDba.Item(i) & vbTab
            Next
            s &= vbCrLf
        End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that your spreadsheet doesn't have header: HDR=No .